# Dictionary printing tuples

Tags: python-2.7

```
TAG_NAME="1.7.0"

 data  = {}
        print data
        data["id"] = project_id,
        data["tag_name"] = TAG_NAME,
        data["ref"] = "master"
```

Output

```
{}
data {'tag_name': ('1.7.0',), 'ref': 'master', 'id': (1596041,)}
```

Why am i getting tag_name and id as tuple

Comment: because you created a tuple by adding a comma in the end.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the super fast response. Coming from JAVA background starting of with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redundant comma at the end of those lines, turning the values from scalars to tuples. Remove them and you should be OK:

```
data["id"] = project_id # Comma removed at the end of this line
data["tag_name"] = TAG_NAME # And this one...
data["ref"] = "master"
```